# Need to replace disk in zpool ... confused

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas, raidz, zpool

I need to replace a bad disk in a zpool on FreeNAS.

`zpool status` shows

```
  pool: raid-5x3
 state: ONLINE
 scrub: scrub completed after 15h52m with 0 errors on Sun Mar 30 13:52:46 2014
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    raid-5x3                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada5p2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/a767b8ef-1c95-11e2-af4c-f46d049aaeca  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada8p2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada10p2                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada7p2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: raid2
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  Sufficient replicas exist for
    the pool to continue functioning in a degraded state.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
 scrub: none requested
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    raid2                                           DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
        gptid/5f3c0517-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/5fe33556-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
        gptid/60570005-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/60ebeaa5-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/61925b86-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

`glabel status` shows

```
                                      Name  Status  Components
                             ufs/FreeNASs3     N/A  da0s3
                             ufs/FreeNASs4     N/A  da0s4
                    ufsid/4fa405ab96518680     N/A  da0s1a
                            ufs/FreeNASs1a     N/A  da0s1a
                            ufs/FreeNASs2a     N/A  da0s2a
gptid/5f3c0517-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada1p2
gptid/60570005-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada3p2
gptid/60ebeaa5-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada4p2
gptid/a767b8ef-1c95-11e2-af4c-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada6p2
gptid/61925b86-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada9p2
gptid/4599731b-8f15-11e1-a14c-f46d049aaeca     N/A  ada10p2
```

`camcontrol devlist` shows

```
<Hitachi HDS723030BLE640 MX6OAAB0>  at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,ada0)
<ST3000VX000-9YW166 CV13>          at scbus4 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,ada1)
<ST3000VX000-9YW166 CV13>          at scbus6 target 0 lun 0 (pass3,ada3)
<Hitachi HDS723030BLE640 MX6OAAB0>  at scbus7 target 0 lun 0 (pass4,ada4)
<ST3000DM001-9YN166 CC4C>          at scbus8 target 0 lun 0 (pass5,ada5)
<WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0 80.00A80>    at scbus8 target 1 lun 0 (pass6,ada6)
<WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0 80.00A80>    at scbus9 target 0 lun 0 (pass7,ada7)
<ST3000DM001-9YN166 CC4C>          at scbus9 target 1 lun 0 (pass8,ada8)
<Hitachi HDS723030BLE640 MX6OAAB0>  at scbus10 target 0 lun 0 (pass9,ada9)
<Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630 MEAOA580>  at scbus11 target 0 lun 0 (pass10,ada10)
< USB Flash Memory 1.00>           at scbus12 target 0 lun 0 (pass11,da0)
```

I'm pretty sure that `ada2` is the bad disk.

It appears that I left a spare in there - **ada0** - last time I was in the box.
Can I replace **ada2** with **ada0** remotely? Until someone gets to the office? With what commands?

Here's what I don't understand:

1. Why don't **ada0, ada2, ada5, ada7,** and **ada8** appear in `glabel status`?
2. Why does `zpool status` show those long gptid's for some disks, and "ada" names for others?
3. If I want to `zpool replace raid2` -- what do I use for the device and new-device names?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**FreeNAS** is a NAS solution, as such, some technical choices are hidden behind whatever firmware, system or GUI such appliance can use.

If you get the partition schema used on a given disk inside a ZFS pool made with **FreeNAS** (small VM example):

```
$ glabel status
                                      Name  Status  Components
gptid/a699226f-bcc4-11e3-952d-0800271cd34d     N/A  ada4p2
gptid/a6cfc072-bcc4-11e3-952d-0800271cd34d     N/A  ada5p2
gptid/a707f034-bcc4-11e3-952d-0800271cd34d     N/A  ada6p2
```

A closer look to the disk `ada4`:

```
$ gpart show ada4
=>      34  62914493  ada4  GPT  (30G)
        34        94        - free -  (47k)
       128   4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
   4194432  58720095     2  freebsd-zfs  (28G)
```

**FreeNAS** is adding a small *swap* partition on each added disk, the remaining disk space being on the 2nd partition (aka `p2` for `ada4p2`).

**Why ?**

Why not. IMHO, it might have something to do with [partition alignment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/sun-unified-storage/documentation/partitionalign-111512-1875560.pdf), but it can also be simply because **FreeNAS** is usually installed on a USB key or some small CF drive without any *swap* (or one being the excuse for the other).

About your questions:

1. **Why don't ada0, ada2, ada5, ada7, and ada8 appear in glabel status?**

   `glabel` is the short for GEOM labelling. So it only displays information regarding supported partitions/fs (see [man glabel](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?glabel%288%29) for a more complete list of supported partitions). In this case, the disks themselves and the swap partitions are not shown.
2. **Why does `zpool status` show those long gptid's for some disks, and "ada" names for others?**

   Same as question 1: because of GEOM labelling, or in that particular case, lack of it.

   Sometimes partitions not initiated/labelled through glabel (or they loose this information ). In all cases: don't worry too much, this is only a naming thing. So it would not be the end of the world if one partition is having a gptid and the other a simple device name.

   Of course, you cannot change the label once the partitions are in a zpool (the system of preventing you from modifying used partitions - make sense).
3. **If I want to `zpool replace raid2` -- what do I use for the device and new-device names?**

   As seen, it might be better to let **FreeNAS** set things for you regarding the disks partitioning: [replacing a failed drive on **FreeNAS**](http://doc.freenas.org/9.3/freenas_storage.html#replacing-a-failed-drive).

   However, it is also possible to do it by hand without worrying about partitioning (the re-silvering will kick-in automatically and would last about the time you are used while doing a scrub - to give you a magnitude order):

   ```
   $ zpool replace raid2 gptid/5fe33556-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca /dev/ada0
   ```

   Once the re-silvering is done, you would have something like that:

   ```
   $ zpool status raid2
     pool: raid2
    state: ONLINE
     scan: resilvered ...G in ?h?m with 0 errors on Sun Apr  6 17:17:25 2014
   config:

           NAME                                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
           NAME                                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
           raid2                                             ONLINE       0     0     0
             raidz1                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
               gptid/5f3c0517-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca    ONLINE       0     0     0
               replacing-0
                 gptid/5fe33556-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
                 ada0                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
               gptid/60570005-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca    ONLINE       0     0     0
               gptid/60ebeaa5-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca    ONLINE       0     0     0
               gptid/61925b86-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca    ONLINE       0     0     0
   ```

   Then a `zpool detach raid2 gptid/5fe33556-3ff2-11e2-9437-f46d049aaeca` to remove the faulty device from the zpool.

   You could still plan for a better/more "in-line" replacement when you have a new disk exchanged for the faulty one. I advise you to carefully set things on a VM and prepare all that (as it seems you are new to this).

   ZFS is a nice filesystem with lot of great features **BUT** it requires planning.

**For more information**:

- [ZFS and partition alignment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/sun-unified-storage/documentation/partitionalign-111512-1875560.pdf)
- [man glabel](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?glabel%288%29)
- [Replacing a failed drive with **FreeNAS**](http://doc.freenas.org/9.3/freenas_storage.html#replacing-a-failed-drive)

Comment: Very good answer. I wasn't aware of what FreeNAS did behind the scenes, coming from the Nexenta and Linux ZFS worlds.

Comment: FreeNAS adds a small swap partition not for alignment, but because replacement disks may not be exactly the same size - if the replacement disk is smaller then it can't be used, adding a swap partition to use a small amount of space makes sure this can't happen, because the partition  for zfs on the existing disk will be 2-3 GB smaller, ensuring the new disk isn't smaller.

Answer (score 16):

I think you should reconsider your use of [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org).  You've had an [uncharacteristically](https://serverfault.com/questions/586952/freenas-swap-pager-i-o-error-pagein-failed). [large](https://serverfault.com/questions/586949/freenas-var-write-failed-filesystem-is-full). [number](https://serverfault.com/questions/586847/need-to-replace-disk-in-zpool-confused). of [issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/586798/need-to-identify-disk-in-zpool-how). [with](https://serverfault.com/questions/457286/freenas-renaming-a-zpool). [your](https://serverfault.com/questions/455474/freenas-expanding-volume). [FreeNAS](https://serverfault.com/questions/418870/freenas-confusion-not-sure-what-happened-raidz1-degraded-disk-faulted). [installation(s)](https://serverfault.com/questions/419007/understanding-smartctl-a-output). [over](https://serverfault.com/questions/586782/zpool-status-reports-error-what-next). the [years](https://serverfault.com/questions/418988/what-is-a-hot-spare-on-freenas).

Many of these issues were planning and ZFS design problems. It may be time to refactor or rebuild your environment now that you have some knowledge of [best or better-practices](http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/03/readme1st.html).