# zpool import one or more devices is currently unavailable

Tags: zfs

zfs drives from a FreeNAS that wouldn't power up after a move. Pulled the disks, scrapped the box, now I can't import any pools. I've tried zfs on Linux and freeNAS from shell on my laptop (using usb/IDE adapter for disk).

System complains that pool may be in use from other system, gives last accessed machine and date.

Import -f complains one or more devices is currently unavailable.

Am I screwed?

Comment: Maybe? What is it about FreeNAS that causes people to have [so many problems](http://serverfault.com/q/586847/13325) with ZFS?

Comment: Where any of the disks on a RAID controller of some type on the original box?  The "pool may be in use by another system" is to be expected.  The "unavailable devices", assuming you have all the original devices, not so much.

Comment: I wasn't aware so many people had trouble with FreeNAS, so I chalked it up 100% to my own ignorance. I don't recall much about the setup except that I had 100% of my disk space available, so nothing was mirrored. I've considered picking up another Dimension 4600 (it's what I used before) since they are about $40, but the wife will give me a TON of crap if it doesn't work :)