# Replaced a dead disk in a ZFS pool. After resilvering finished, the status look weird :/

Tags: zfs, truenas, zpool, pool

I replaced a dead disk in a ZFS pool (on FreeNAS-11.1-U6.3) following the hints I found at [Need to replace disk in zpool ... confused](https://serverfault.com/questions/586847/need-to-replace-disk-in-zpool-confused) ...

```
# zpool replace raid2 gptid/f00-whatever-id-that-was-f46d049aaeca /dev/ada0
```

and after resilvering for 20 hours, the pool is healthy and online again... so thanks a lot to the original poster & replies \o/ :D

There's one thing though that's annoying me: The current result of a `zpool status jake` command. It looks quite weird:

```
# zpool status jake
  pool: jake
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 3.24T in 0 days 20:21:41 with 0 errors on Wed Jan  9 16:04:10 2019
config:

        NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        jake                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/c735d419-f00-dead-beef-924a3908f2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada1                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/adc35419-f00-dead-beef-924a3908f2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/f50d12c3-f00-dead-beef-924a3908f2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/acab0c73-f00-dead-beef-924a3908f2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

So... `ada1` instead of `gptid/whatever` :(
It looks like I didn't initialize and/or specify the new HD correctly?

How can I fix this? Removing it from the pool, initiaize it correctly and then re-add it?

Thanks for your help,

R

Comment: The previous question did you link to did include a link to the glabel man page.  Did you read that one?  Pretty sure that is how you would have set a label.

Comment: Why don't use just use the GUI?  It does all the lifting you need (encryption if applicable, labeling, assigning the correct device, create partition table, setting up swap, reducing the size slightly so you can replace even with slightly smaller drives, etc). And that's the whole point of using a NAS appliance, in contrast to vanilla FreeBSD, isn't it? Your problem: You assigned a whole disk by device id rather than assigning a partition by label.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me to the GUI!
I finally found the place in the GUI where I can add a replacement HDD in the proper way. Before that I overlooked the right menu again and again.
Using the GUI was indeed straightforward & did all the necessary steps.

Of course I first had to remove the ada1 drive here and replaced it with a new, empty one.

Comment: Can you please expand on where the place in GUI is? This looks exactly like the problem I am having, but I can't for the love of god find how to fix it